# How to have a fixed navigation bar that doesn't change size when you scroll down?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

My navigation bar spans the width of the page but when I write `object: fixed;`, the navigation bar shrinks and goes over the text. I would like the navigation bar to be like [dootrix.com](http://dootrix.com), where it is sort of ingrained in the website and does not shrink when you scroll down!

I have created a JSFiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/kpsq8r9m/

Here is my CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: darkgrey;
  border-width: 6px;
  position: fixed;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: What I meant when it was "shrinking" was if I did not have position:fixed; it would extend to the entire page but when I did it shrunk. In order to see what I am talking about I would recommend trying this out in google chrome.

Comment: Try  to add Z-index on your css

Comment: I'm not seeing a shrinking effect.

Comment: The wordpress template your using implements [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). If you look at both the source code for the template and bootstrap, it will help you get a better idea to do what you're looking for

Comment: Your fiddle appears to already demonstrate a fixed header that doesn't shrink when the page is scrolled down. Can you please ensure you've provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, `object:` isn't a valid CSS selector. Perhaps you're looking for `object-fit:` or `object-position:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

`z-index:100` should do the trick.

Comment: Wait do I add that in ul, or do I create an entirely thing called .navbar-fixed?

Comment: I tried that but then I got a little bit of extra space on the left side and now the borders are completely messed up.